# Soundcloud Javascript SDK 2.0 returns 404 when downloading audiomanager.js

Tags: soundcloud

The Soundcloud Javascript SDK sends a GET request to audiomanager.js. This is returning a 404 and cannot stream as a result.

This seems to be a bug on Soundcloud's side as this was working last night and no changes were made to my implementation.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/xkrfd940/

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

If you look at your browser's console, you'll see a 404 error when soundcloud tries to download AudioManager. Wasn't getting this error last night.

Any suggestions on getting this sorted out would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show more code pls?

Comment: updated with a JSFiddle

Comment: same here, with sdk init

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved now. See this github issue for details.

https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/20

Comment: thanks for sharing, was not aware that they give support on github as well.